# Error while deploying firebase function with Stripe

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying deploy firebase function with Stripe but that complain on some manifest.
If you have at least idea in what file that should be, please also suggest.
In advance, thanks!

Maksym

Here is error code:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
Require stack:
 - /learning-react/functions/src/index.js
 - /learning-react/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js
 - /learning-react/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/bin/firebase-functions.js
```

package.json in **functions** directory:

```
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.13.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.42.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

package.json in **learn-react** directory, I am not sure if I need two json files.

```
{
  "name": "learning-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.6.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.13.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.42.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.3",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-easy-crop": "^4.4.2",
    "react-image-crop": "^10.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.4.5",
    "style-components": "^0.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "uid": "^2.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

If some more information demands, please tell me.

Comment: Can you check whether stripe is listed under the dependencies of the package.json?

Comment: Can you please share more info about your actual code? Have you added the Stripe node package properly?

Comment: I used 
*npm i @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js* 
in learn-react directory

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne , I provided JSON as you asked

Comment: @NolanH look now, I added to post a few JSON

Comment: I think you don't need @stripe/react-stripe-js package to be installed inside the functions. Is there any reason for installing that? As far as I see it's a stripe package for React Js. Since you are using stripe with firebase cloud functions you don't need it. So can you try removing it and try again.

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne No, that didn't work.

Comment: Can you try run "npm install stripe" inside the functions directory. Seems like stripe package is required for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated packages JSON, it looks like you're missing the `stripe` package for `stripe-node`: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#installation

You've included the Stripe.js module helper and React package, which are for client-side pieces of your integration. For server-side secret requests you need stripe-node.